# SPWeb.Webs, Site vs SubSite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am confused between `SPSite`, `SiteCollection`, and `SPWeb`?

So my understanding is this pseudo code:

```
 http://My_server >>> TOP Level SIte or SPWEbApplication
 http://My_server/My_site >>>> Site Collection or SPSite
```

Now a site under `SPSite` that will be referenced through `SPWeb`. So what are we getting when using `SPWeb.Webs`?

What is a Subsite?

---

Test code:

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPWebCollection sites = mySite.Webs;

foreach (SPWeb subSite in sites)
{
    Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(subSite.Title) + "<BR>");
}
```

Comment: The official documentation from microsoft is at: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The top level site collection `SPSite` is a container in which you have your root web `SPWeb` and subsites `SPWebs` under `SPWebs` - it takes a while to get used to the names.

Here's a nice diagram referenced from Microsoft:

[image]

Therefore, **a subsite will be any site `SPWeb` under the top level web site in a site collection `SPSite`**.

Answer (score 2):

The top level site is also referred to as the Root Web `SPSite.RootWeb`.