# What is the difference between SharePoint Web and Site

Tags: sharepoint-2010, spweb, spsite

Could anybody explain the difference between SP.Web and SP.Site entities?
As I understand SP.Site contains different SP.Webs, that represent SiteCollections. Is it correct? Could you please share any links for better understanding this approach?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically:

```
UI Term          API Class Name
-------          --------------
Site Collection  SPSite
Site             SPWeb
```

For further information, see the following:

[SPWeb.Webs, Site vs SubSite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549530/spweb-webs-site-vs-subsite)

[Getting my head round spsite vs spweb vs anything else](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/getting-my-head-round-spsite-vs-spweb-vs-anything-else)

[SPSite vs SPWeb, Site Collection vs Site](http://blog.mediawhole.com/2009/02/spsite-vs-spweb-site-collection-vs-site.html)